# Regex to find text after the first comma

Tags: regex

I would like a regex to delete the text after the first comma and delete the second comma. There are always three commas, but the characters in the text change.

first text:0,second text:1,third text:4,None:0

So that I end up with the following text:

first text:0,third text:4,None:0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not just split and join the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search using regex:

```
^([^,]*),[^,]*(.*)$
```

and replace by:

```
$1$2
```

where `$1` and `$2` are captured groups 1 and 2.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dD0vT3/1)

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! That works great. Is there any chance you can explain so that I might understand it better.

Comment: Sure, check demo link I provided. On right hand side full regex is available. Basically `([^,]*` matches 0 or more of any character that is not comma and `(...)` is used for capturing groups.

Comment: For some reason you have to wait a while before you can select an answer.